# Meaning of "community adolescents" in a research study

Tags: phrase-meaning, translation

From "[Early Variations in White Matter Microstructure and Depression Outcome in Adolescents With Subthreshold Depression](https://ajp.psychiatryonline.org/doi/10.1176/appi.ajp.2018.17070825)":

> Neuroimaging and clinical data were obtained from a large sample of **community adolescents** recruited around age 14 in middle schools from eight sites in four European countries (www.imagen-europe.com). A detailed description of recruitment and assessment procedures, with exclusion and inclusion criteria, has been published elsewhere (14).

What is the meaning of "community adolescents"? Does it mean that they all belong to some typical "school community", spend their time in typical school environments?  A boy/girl of the same age but belonging to a shepherd community in Afghanistan would not fit this "group"? Or does it mean "any adolescent that lives in **any kind** of community"?

I want to translate this sentence into Russian, and cannot understand the precise meaning.

The abstract of the article uses the term "community-based cohort":

> Adolescents with subthreshold depression (N=96) and healthy control subjects (N=336) drawn from a **community-based cohort** were compared using diffusion tensor imaging and whole brain tract-based spatial statistics (TBSS) at age 14 to assess white matter microstructure.

Comment: adolescents of the community

Comment: This seems to be a request for clarification of a particular text, rather than a question about English language itself. So far as the language itself is concerned, *community adolescents* simply means adolescents from/in some community. In some scientific literature, saying that somebody lives in the community is intended to convey that the person does not live in some specialised institution. Whether this is what these particular authors intended can be ascertained only by asking them, if it is not clear from the context.

Answer (score 0):

It means those adolescents were recruited from the community in which the research study was taking place.

Comment: But there were 8 sites spread across Europe, so it's not the same single community.

Comment: @CowperKettle: No, it wouldn't be. However, whenever they needed recruits in, say, Madrid, they did not travel to Amsterdam to get them. Substitute "local" for "community," see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The middle schools are in communities. Therefore, those are adolescents in the communities where the schools are located.

I think you can just not translate it. It just confuses things.

Comment: So it's kind of a redundant word, because of course a school pupil would come to his/her school from the local community, unless they are a billionaire's kids and are delivered each day by a personal jet?

Comment: It is just not needed. Most kids are from the "community". Unless it's a boarding school. :)

Comment: So the word "community" must then stress this fact: that they live in their families in free time, and not on school grounds. Then it's not redundant and might be relevant, and thus should be translated somehow.

Comment: I dunno,  it's up to you.  I can say the text is somewhat iffy.  middle schools from sites? No, it should be: middle schools from locations. I'm too tired today to fight against eurospeak. :)